# Export react component to external domains (including styles)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I managed to export the output of `npm run build` (of create-react-app), which I modified in `index.js` like so:

```
window.inject = (rootElem) => {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElem);
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  window.codeBuilder = window.inject(document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

Then I run `npm run build && serve -s build`,
So in the external domain I load my component like so:

```
<div id="myComponentHere"></div>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.inject(document.querySelector('#myComponentHere'));
</script>
```

The problem is that I don't get the css styles with it. Is there a package or a cleaner way for me to include styles in an encapsulated way (without iframe or manually loading styles?)

Answer (score 0):

To do this we need to:

- Bundle and inject the CSS from the JS file
- Ensure that our CSS class name selectors won't collide with the destination page

##### For injecting the CSS with JS:

1. Install `webpack-cli` with `npm i -D webpack-cli`

   - Webpack itself is already installed with CRA
2. Bundle the project with one of two approaches:

   - Bundle the CRA build with the config from [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3365#issuecomment-376546407)
   - Bundle your project directly by setting the entry to `index.js`
3. For both approaches, ensure that your webpack is configured to output a JS file:

```
output: {
 filename: "main.js",
}
```

4. Serve your file, `npx webpack serve`
   a. If you're bundling your CRA build, make sure to build it first.

##### For avoiding CSS classname collisions

1. Name any bundled CSS file `[name].module.css`.

   - Having `module` in the file name is really important here for the Webpack and other bundlers to transform the CSS files properly, hash class names, and export those hashes to your modules.
2. Exclusively use those CSS modules in your component.

###### CSS Example:

###### `Component.module.css`

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.warning {
  color: red;
}
```

###### `Component.js`

```js
import styles from './Component.module.css'

const Component = () => (
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <p className={styles.warning}>Warning</p>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Is there a way no to affect the global css scope? and bundle it inside the js bundle?

Comment: For the second point. Absolutely. You'll need to configure a bundler to do that. I'm not sure if it can be done with webpack or a webpack plugin, but Vite has [vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js) which does exactly what you want. Just be careful if you decide to eject or migrate. For the first question, for the styles to apply, you'd have to add them to the scope, you just need to make sure the selectors won't collide with the destination. You can import your css as module: `import styles from './styles.cs'` `className=styles.container`

Comment: With css modules, imported class names are converted to hashes to avoid global collisions. While not 100% guaranteed to not collide with the destination page, it's very unlikely.

Comment: @funerr Also check [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3365#issuecomment-376546407) out

Comment: can you add it to your answer (specifically how to integrate to `create-react-app` so i'll mark it as a solution?

Comment: Updated the asnwer. Let me know if you run into any trouble!